# _.bind source code in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

read the `_.bind` in source code, I didn't understand when the statement `this instanceof bound` will be true. Could anyone give an example.

```
_.bind = function(func, context) {
    var args, bound;
    if (nativeBind && func.bind === nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    if (!_.isFunction(func)) throw new TypeError;
    args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return bound = function() {
      if (!(this instanceof bound)) return func.apply(context, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
      var self = new ctor;
      ctor.prototype = null;
      var result = func.apply(self, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      if (Object(result) === result) return result;
      return self;
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, `Function.prototype.bind` won't be defined.  If `bound` is used as a constructor, `(this instanceof bound)` will be true.  For example:

```
Function.prototype.bind = null;
var Constructor = function () {};
var BoundConstructor = _.bind(Constructor, {});
var b = new BoundConstructor();  // (this instanceof bound) === true
```

You can use the debugger to trace through [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDF6e/).

Comment: in which scenario will use the bound as constructor? When a function is used as constructor, is necessary to bind context?

Comment: `bound` is a constructor whenever it is used with the `new` keyword.  JS constructors always bind `this` to the newly created object; hence, the special logic in `_.bind`.